# Язык Си не пойму почему ругается gcc

Tags: c, gcc

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]

```
*rem = (n - ( (base << 1) + (qq & ~7ul)));
```

и вот тоже с предупреждением

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
>   [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

```
*rem = (unsigned char)(n - ( (base << 1) + (qq & ~7ul)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас одна или более из используемых в формуле переменных является указателем и вы её не разыменовываете(т.е. не ставите * перед именем). Какая именно я сказать не могу т.к. нужен еще код объявления всех переменных.